How can I extend/append a Vec<String>?
I want to extend/append a Vec<String> which seems like it ought to be easy, but I'm chasing my tail trying to get it to work.  I have:
fn main() {
    // Helper Function
    fn init () -> Vec<String> {
        vec!["string one"].into_iter().map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect()
    }

    let mut res = init();
    println!("res: {:?}", res); // fine so far
    let next_string = String::from("string two");
    res = res.push(next_string);
    println!("res: {:?}", res);
}

The output I want is ["string one", "string two"] but I get a mismatch error:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:11
   |
7  |     let mut res = init();
   |                   ------ expected due to this value
...
10 |     res = res.push(next_string);
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Vec<String>`, found `()`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Vec<String>`
           found unit type `()`
note: method `push` modifies its receiver in-place
  --> src/main.rs:10:15
   |
10 |     res = res.push(next_string);
   |           --- ^^^^ this call modifies `res` in-place
   |           |
   |           you probably want to use this value after calling the method...
   = note: ...instead of the `()` output of method `push`

New to Rust so this could be something silly or a fundamental misunderstanding!  Examples in the documentation involve integers, not String so I'm having trouble figuring this out.

Remove res = before res.push(next_string);. Pushing modifies in place, no need to reassign as well.

That's what the compiler message was about!  Usually the messages are more helpful.  Thank you.  Glad to accept an answer if you post as one.

Ugh!    I see that the documentation did not assign but modified in place... I was too focused on the wrong thing!

The documentation example assigns in place, but there's nothing in the documentation explanation that a newbie would interpret as assigning in place. I guess it must be the &mut self argument that tells us that the assignment modifies the existing value.  Is that true?

Yes, that's correct. You should read up more on rust ownership rules, in particular when you would need to assign back to the original variable (generally, only if you're consuming it in the function call).

Well the biggest clue of them all is the return type of push which is just a unit, no information, it doesn't make much sense to assign "no information" to a variable.

Eventually, I understood that the return type of push is just (), but looking at the documentation it doesn't seem to give the return type.  Again, recall I am a new learner, there's a lot to absorb.  Thanks for the perspective!

fn foo() is shorthand for fn foo() -> (). I.e. if there isn't an explicit return type nothing is returned.

@cafce25: Just to be smart: it returns the only value of the unit type. Nothing would be never (!).
;-)

@Matthias: Just to be smart: nothing as in "no information", also never means it does not return, not that it returns nothing.
